# Show all categories only in K2 Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

I want to show only category in my product page using k2, but when I choose from menu, it shows items from that category. how can I fix this ?

Just want to show only category list with thumbnail, there after when user clicks on the category, it should show all items regarding to category.

Second task is when user clicks on all items menu, show all items and thumbnails.

How can I do this heavy stuff ?

Comment: i think you need to learn, its project assignment, here you can discuss code level issues and problems

Comment: @Naeem... no its not a project assignment... i am learning joomla and k2... and i m doing same as per tutorials in getk2... but its not working... what should be the main problem behind this ?

Comment: one more thing... how can i change template for items/product listing ???

Comment: share your current code and problem you are facing in it.

Comment: anyways, i found solution... just created k2cat module using K2 tools module and it worked for me... i made sidebar and put module code in that sidebar in index.php .... yupppyyyy happyyyy ... :)

Comment: then you can answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

To do this please

1. edit or add a new menu item
2. Choose menu type: K2 > Latest from on or more category
3. Choose the category you wish
4. Play with ON-OFFs to get the layout you need!

Hope this helps!